# data-..atributes isn't highlighted in my html bootstrap code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add carousel on my website but it seems that  data-ride isn't highlighted in my code. It is  perfectly highlighted in stackoverflow, but not in Notepad++. Lately I've noticed that other data-... attributes aren't highlighted also. I expect there to be carousel, but images are just stacked. Here is the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BFhr.png

```
<!-- SLIDESHOW-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- indicators dot nav-->

                <!-- wrapper for slides-->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/tepih1.jpg" alt="tepisi" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">

                            <h1> Tepih1 </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/tepih2.jpg" alt="tepisi" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">

                            <h1> Tepih2 </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- controls or next and prev buttons-->
```

Comment: The fact the data-ride attribute is not being highlighted in your text editor isn't the reason why your carousel is not working properly. Have you imported bootstrap js files? Is there any error in your console?

Comment: I've imported them locally. I noticed that any data-... attribute isn't highlighted

Comment: Hi - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below one of the answers, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean about the data-ride attribute not being highlighted by Notepad++. If none of what follows solves your problem, please post a screenshot *(the StackOverflow question editor has a toolbar button for uploading a picture)*.

#### Suggestions:

(1) Try referencing the bootstrap files from a CDN - that will test that it is not a "can't find the file" problem.

```
<head>
    <!-- Other stuff in head... goes here... -->
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

(2) do you have any errors in the dev console (F12) ?

If the same code works in place1 but does not work in place2, the problem isn't the code - it's the environment. Most likely, bootstrap files not being found.

(3) For bootstrap 4, you know that you need to load four files, right? (a) The css, (b) jQuery, (c) popper javascript file, and (d) bootstrap js (loaded in that order - at least, the jQuery must be loaded before the bootstrap js files)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BFhr.png Here is the picture. I've tried to replace your code but didn't work. What other environments can I try? I noticed that other data-... attributes aren't highlighted also

Comment: What version of Notepad++ are you using? Perhaps it is an older version *(the curr version is 7.6.3 - is that the version you are using)*? Anyway, ***that*** is certainly not the problem. The line you highlighted is correct - no problems there. So, I do see the references in the `<head>` to the Bootstrap CSS - do you have refs to the jQuery and BootStrap libraries at bottom of `<body>`? Did you try replacing the HTML tags for Bootstrap/jQuery with CDN references, exactly as shown in my answer above? *(Can you access those CDN libraries from your location?)*

Comment: I've imported other code for carousel and it seems to work fine. I still don't know why my code didn't work.  I'm using 7.6.3 version.  When I installed bootstrap i tried to make green button that disappears once clicked, and it worked, so I'm sure I've installed correctly.

Comment: When I have a problem like this, I start over - just re-doing the carousel (yes, I've had exactly the same problem you are reporting - carousel code looked perfect but didn't work). So, create a new page *with just the carousel on it*. ***Code it from scratch*** (so you don't copy-over that bit of code with the missing `>`), and get the carousel working. Then replace the carousel code in your project with the new code. I bet *dollars-to-donuts* that you've just got a missing character somewhere (probably a `>`) - the trick is to find it ! My standard act is to do as I just suggested - it works